# Right click extended menu on desktop not working fully. (20.04 unity)

Tags: unity, 20.04, nautilus, nemo, nautilus-actions

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 (unity), right click extended menu (resize images, open in terminal etc) wont work on Desktop but it works with file manager --> Desktop.

i follow instructions fixes like "Have file manager handle the desktop" on gnome tweaks and option isn't available anymore.

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the fact that really you have two file-managers - Nautilus (or Files) and Nemo.
The Nautilus is used by default for file browsing, while Nemo (actually `nemo-desktop`) controls the desktop area on the screen. Previously Nautilus had functionality for desktop area, but nowadays this functionality is removed.
So Nautilus and Nemo have two sets of different settings. It may be very hard to fix the inconsistency.

You can try to install the `filemanager-actions` and `nemo-extension-fma` packages to make action settings consistent.

But all this sounds like death of Unity.
As an alternative you may want to try switching to MATE DE with the [Mutiny panel layout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7P_2IYF9AMU) which tends to replace Unity:

> [image: Mutiny panel layout in Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS]

Comment: That seems to be the issue, there is no way to use an alternative that works as file management on desktop area? i dont really like mate.

Comment: How can i make nautilus as my only file manager?

Comment: Modern Nautilus [can't control the desktop area](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115/17?u=norbert), this is why I'm recommending MATE. I do not know other fluent consistent desktop environments with Unity-like functionality. You can try to adapt the Xfce or KDE for your needs, but it will be harder than using MATE.

Comment: I see, using nemo with unity is a good idea?

Comment: You have to test it by yourself. Using Nemo as desktop manager and Nautilus as file-manager is better than nothing. But Nautilus itself is less functional than Nemo (from Cinnamon) or Caja (from MATE). So Unity is now dying and lose polished functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Tweaks=>Keyboard and mouse=>Mouse click animation=>

Tick the option which says "Double tap on pad with 2 fingers" and do that with the icon. It will bring back all the options to rename, open with etc.